# Вопрос не приемлем

Tags: php, html, комментарии

------------------Нет вопроса.

Comment: Господи, я не умею задавать вопросы

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста вопрос текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не вопрос а непонятно что.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Для этого нужно на сервере проверять, имеет ли текущий пользователь права на удаление комментария с данным Id

Comment: на самом деле можно через js заинкапсулировать id комента, если проблема только в явном показе idшника